# Wave equation in a cube

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Is it possible find a computable solution to the following homogeneous wave equation problem:
Let $\mathcal{C}=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3, 0< x,y,z < 1\} $ be the open unit cube. Find $u$ such that 
\begin{align*}
&\partial_t^2 -\Delta u =0, ~(t,\hat{x})\in \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathcal{C}
\\ &u(0,x)=\partial_tu(0,x)=0 ,~\hat{x} \in \overline{\mathcal{C}}
\end{align*}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Here](http://faculty.nps.edu/bneta/pde.pdf) is something that might help (page 263).

Comment: Thank you! It looks helpful.